# Android: Get XML from URL with HTTPClient

Tags: java, android, xml, http, url

I am trying to get an `XML` document from `URL`. I know I should not do this on the UI thread, so I start a new one:

```
Thread t  = new Thread(new GetXML());
t.start();
```

This starts the inner class `GetXML` which implements `Runnable`.

```
private class GetXML implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String xmlString = getXmlFromUrl(<URL of the XML as String>);
        Document xmlDoc = getDomElement(xmlString);
        String textValue = getTextValue(pointWhereItBreaks, xmlDoc, "movie");
    }
}
```

As you can see, this executes a few methods, but the problem is already in the first one `getXmlFromUrl`:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String xmlUrl) {
    String xmlString = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(xmlUrl);
        //the following line causes the problem
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return xmlString;
}
```

I have located the line where it breaks. It doesn't pass the following line:

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Does anybody can tell me how to fix the code? I am stuck at this problem for days. I am able to get `XML` documents by a `URL` when I run a java application from my computer with a similar code. Why does it not work with Android?

Thank you very much!

Comment: do you have the Internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: post logcat so we can see the problem

Comment: Yes, I've enabled the Internet permission in the manifest. Anyways thanks!
What is meant with the logcat? The one I can see in eclipse is constantly changing.

Comment: You use a `HTTP-POST` for `GET`ting the XML intentionally?

Comment: I've extracted this from a tutorial. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: Try HttpGet see if that works. Also if you can try to use the built in AsyncTask class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Unfortunately `HttpGet` made no difference. I will read something about the AsyncTask, to try this.